# Error in registering the controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

My code is like this

```
App.js
angular.module('mailerApp', [
    'mailerApp.services',
    'mailerApp.controllers',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'textAngular',
    'angularFileUpload'
]);

Cotrollers.js
angular.module('mailerApp.controllers').controller('MailerCntrl', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function ($scope, FileUploader) {

}]);

Services.JS
angular.module('mailerApp.services', []).factory('rateRequestService', ['$http', rateRequestService]);
function rateRequestService($http) {
    var service = { getData: getData };
    return service;
    function getData() {
        return $http({
            method: 'Get',
            url: '../services/RateRequestWS.asmx/GetReadOnlyData?'
        });
    }
}

HTML
body ng-app="mailerApp" ng-controller="MailerCntrl">
</body>
```

Everything looks okay to me, But this throws an error

```
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'mailerApp.controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to
 load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
 dependencies as the second argument.
```

Can any one point out What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are creating the module you need to add an empty array as the second argument: `angular.module('mailerApp.controllers', [])` (Just like you have with `mailarApp.services`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
angular.module('mailerApp.controllers').controller...
```

You need to do

```
angular.module('mailerApp').controller... // to add the controller to the mailerApp module
angular.module('mailerApp.controllers', []).controller... // to add the controller to a new mailerApp.controllers module
```

And the same goes with;

```
angular.module('mailerApp.services').factory...
```

Instead you need to

```
angular.module('mailerApp').factory... // add the factory to the mailerApp module
angular.module('mailerApp.services', []).factory... // add the factory to a new mailerApp.services module
```

When you *create* and angular module, you give it a name and the list of dependencies in the array;

```
var module = angular.module('<module_name>', [<dependencies>])
```

But then when you add a controller/factory to the module, you'll need to either use the `module` object you created.

Comment: This is incorrect as he wants `mailerApp.controllers` and `mailerApp.services` as separate modules (as he has added them as dependent modules to his main module).

Comment: @tasseKATT I've added that in the edit to the answer.

Comment: Please also update your answer to remove the first part (which is not correct)

Comment: I've added a more detailed explanation. Thanks @Anzeo

Answer (score 3):

1. when you write `angular.module('mailerApp.controllers', [ ])`, you create new module as `'mailerApp.controllers'` and in second parameter you pass dependencies.
2. and when you write `angular.module('mailerApp.controllers')` it references previously created module.

But in your case your directly referencing module without creating it, therefore it gives you error for that. Same goes for other cases